# Reference request for the dual space of the Bochner Space $L^1(\Omega ; X) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be open and let $X$ be a Banach Space. Let $L^1(\Omega ; X)$ denote the space of all strongly measurable (sometimes also referred to as Bochner Measurable) functions, $f\,\colon\Omega\to X$ such that $$ \int_{\Omega}\left\lVert{f}\right\rVert_X dx<\infty$$
Is there any reference that gives a description of the dual space of $L^1(\Omega;X)$ ?

In particular what I am looking for is a representation for the dual space of $L^1(\Omega; C_0(\mathbb{R}^m))$ where $C_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is the space of continuous functions $\phi\,\colon\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{\lVert x\rVert\to\infty}\phi(x)=0$

Comment: Welcome to MO! In fact, $L^\infty(\Omega;X^*)$ is always isometric to a subspace of the dual of $L^1(\Omega;X)$, and they coincide if and only if $X^*$ has the Radon-Nikodym property, check "Vector Measures" by Diestel&Uhl, Theorem IV.1.1.

Comment: You can find what you need in https://books.google.ca/books?id=MSLUBwAAQBAJ $L^1(X) = L^1\hat{\otimes}X$ the projective tensor product of $L^1$ and $X$. Its dual is the space of all bounded bilinear forms on $L^1\times X$, which can be identified with $L(L^1,X^*)$ and/or $L(L^{\infty},X)$, where $L(E,F)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators $E\to F$.